# How to code categorical values in column basis no of occurrences in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have following dataframe in pandas

```
  id    source
  1     AS
  2     AS
  3     AS
  4     AT
  5     BR
  6     BT
  7     BR
  8     BT
  9     AS
  10    BE
```

What I want to do in above dataframe is whichever source has less than 3 occurrences should be coaded as OTHERS. I have 1 million entries with more than 10K unique sources. How can we do it in pandas.

Desired dataframe is

```
  id    source
  1     AS
  2     AS
  3     AS
  4     OTHERS
  5     OTHERS
  6     OTHERS
  7     OTHERS
  8     OTHERS
  9     AS
  10    OTHERS
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this,

```
df.loc[df.groupby('source').transform('count').lt(3)['id'], 'source'] = 'OTHERS'
```

---

```
   id  source
0   1      AS
1   2      AS
2   3      AS
3   4  OTHERS
4   5  OTHERS
5   6  OTHERS
6   7  OTHERS
7   8  OTHERS
8   9      AS
9  10  OTHERS
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have multiple columns in dataframe do I have to add it along with `id` column?

Comment: I have around 70 columns in the dataframe. Do I have to add all 70 columns?

Comment: If you try ,```df.groupby(by=['source']).transform("count")``` will see what transformation does.